# How to merge two pandas dataframes based on a value in one row and with different column names?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two pandas dataframes that I want to merge. The dataframes are of different sizes so I only want those that appear in `df1` to be kept - some students only appear in one of `df1` or `df2`.

`df1` has the headings `['student', 'week1_count', 'week1_mean', ..., 'week11_count', 'week11_mean']` and is initialised with all cells except the `'student'` column to be zero.

`df2` has the headings `['student', 'week', 'count', 'mean']` and is populated with the corresponding `'student'`. `'week'` is an int between 1-11, and `'count'` and `'mean'` are the corresponding floats.

What I want to do is for a given student in `df1` and `df2`, for a given week, take the corresponding `'count'` and `'mean'` value and put it in `df1` in the corresponding column. For example, a `'week'` value of `1` would mean that the value in `'count'` and `'mean'` in `df2` would be put in `'week1_count'` and `'week1_mean'` respectively in `df1`.

Regarding the weeks I have been looping through `range(11)` and create a subset dataframe but wonder whether there is a quicker way.

i.e.

```
df1:
    student week1_count week1_mean week2_count week2_mean ... 
      '0'        0           0          0            0    ...
      '2'        0           0          0            0    ...
      '3'        0           0          0            0    ...
      .
      .
      .
      '500'      0           0          0            0    ...
      '541'      0           0          0            0    ...
      '542'      0           0          0            0    ...
```

and

```
df2:
    student week count mean
      '0'     1    5    6.5
      '1'     1    3    7.0
      '2'     1    2    8.2
      '2'     2    10   15.1
      .
      .
      .
     '500'    2    12   4.3
     '540'    4    1    3.0
     '542'    1    4    1.2
     '542'    2    9    5.2
```

so the intended result

```
df_result:
    student week1_count week1_mean week2_count week2_mean ... 
      '0'        5           6.5        0            0    ...
      '2'        2           8.2        10           15.1 ...
      '7'        0           0          0            0    ...
      .
      .
      .
      '500'      0           0          12           4.3  ...
      '541'      0           0          0            0    ...
      '542'      4           1.2        9            5.2  ...
```

I have tried various routines - none of which have worked as intended - in pandas such as:

- merge:
  using a 'left' join as I want the format of `df1`. I tried renaming the columns in `df2` to match column names.
- join
- concat
- update:
  tried initialising all cells in `df1` to `np.nan` rather than `0.0` and then use `df1.update(df2)` (after renaming cols in `df2`) to update all nan values with the intended one
- tried to just set the values:
  i.e. something like `df1[rows_in_both][['week1_count','week1_mean']] = df2[rows_in_both][['count','mean']]` but that didn't work either

Comment: @W-B have tried `left_on` and `right_on` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a `update` problem ***rather than*** `merge`

```
s=df2.pivot(index='student',columns='week',values=['count','mean'])# pivot df2 to format it to df1 like . 
s.columns.map('week{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format) # modify the column
Out[645]: 
Index(['week1_count', 'week2_count', 'week4_count', 'week1_mean', 'week2_mean',
       'week4_mean'],
      dtype='object')
s.columns=s.columns.map('week{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
```

Then we doing `update`

```
df1=df1.set_index('student')
df1=df1.update(s)
```

Comment: Great thank you! I had unsuccessfully tried using `update` Just a question, when I run that it appears to work but on running the last line I get a syntax error 'SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 4, 'df1=df1.update(s).reset_index()'))'. Do you know why?